# How does number of points change a FFT in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, correlation

When taking `fft(signal, nfft)` of a signal, how does nfft change the outcome and why? Can I have a fixed value for nfft, say `2^18`, or do I need to go `2^nextpow2(2*length(signal)-1)`?

I am computing the power spectral density(PSD) of two signals by taking the FFT of the autocorrelation, and I want to compare the the results. Since the signals are of different lengths, I am worried if I don't fix nfft, it would make the comparison really hard!

Answer (score 3):

There is no inherent reason to use a power-of-two (it just might make the processing more efficient in some circumstances).

However, to make the FFTs of two different signals "commensurate", you will indeed need to zero-pad one or other (or both) signals to the same lengths before taking their FFTs.

---

However, I feel obliged to say: If you need to ask this, then you're probably not at a point on the DSP learning curve where you're going to be able to do anything useful with the results.  You should get yourself a decent book on DSP theory, e.g. [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Understanding-Digital-Signal-Processing-Richard/dp/0137027419/).

Answer (score 3):

Most modern FFT implementations (including MATLAB's which is based on FFTW) now rarely require padding a signal's time series to a length equal to a power of two.  However, nearly all implementations will offer better, and sometimes much much better, performance for FFT's of data vectors w/ a power of 2 length.  For MATLAB specifically, padding to a power of 2 or to a length with many low prime factors will give you the best performance (N = 1000 = 2^3 * 5^3 would be excellent, N = 997 would be a terrible choice).

Zero-padding will not increase frequency resolution in your PSD, however it does reduce the bin-size in the frequency domain.  So if you add NZeros to a signal vector of length N the FFT will now output a vector of length ( N + NZeros )/2 + 1.  This means that each bin of frequencies will now have a width of:

> Bin width (Hz)  = F_s / ( N + NZeros )

Where F_s is the signal sample frequency.

If you find that you need to separate or identify two closely space peaks in the frequency domain, you need to increase your sample **time**.  You'll quickly discover that zero-padding buys you nothing to that end - and intuitively that's what we'd expect.  How can we expect more information in our power spectrum w/o adding more information (longer time series) in our input?

Best,

Paul